# Explanation of the topology on Rational Numbers

Tags: general-topology, rational-numbers

Is there any notes, lecture notes, journals and such that caters "Topology on Rational Numbers Q"? Please help.

Comment: Any specific aspects? The (standard metric and) topology on $\Bbb Q$ might be discussed to some extent in virtually every introduction to topology

Comment: I don't actually think if this is possible but, can I like, seek for closure of A s.t. A is a subset of X and X=Q? or Interior, Exterior and Boundary of A? Thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: This topology is indeed the one inherited from the reals. But it can be characterised (up to homeomorphism) as the only countable metric space without isolated points. See http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.pdf for proofs.

Comment: Hey Laurence; I think this can be made into a decent question. It would help, maybe, if you *edited the question* to say a few words about (1) what your background is in topology (if that's "none", you can say that) and (2) what your interest is in $\Bbb Q$ specifically (a specific problem, or trying to gain intuition, or learning definitions, or etc. etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As von Eitzen mentions, this material is fairly standard in any introductory topology text. For instance, you can find many of the relevant statements and their proofs on ProofWiki: the [rational numbers](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Rational_Number) are a [totally separated](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Totally_Separated) but [non-discrete](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_not_Discrete_Space) [countable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Countably_Infinite) [metric subspace of $\Bbb R$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_form_Metric_Subspace_of_Real_Numbers_under_Euclidean_Metric), which as a subspace is [dense](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rationals_are_Everywhere_Dense_in_Reals) [$F_\sigma$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_form_F-Sigma_Set_in_Reals) but [not $G_\delta$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_of_Rational_Numbers_is_not_G-Delta_Set_in_Reals). Other intrinsic facts about its topology (and most of their proofs) are collected on [this subpage](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Category:Rational_Number_Space), although if you run around in the wiki for a while you'll find several more which are not.

ProofWiki is not the most easy site to read, in my opinion, but I don't think you're going to find a more complete collection of results in one place, just because the material is so standard.

Answer (score 3):

When we talk about topology on $\mathbb{Q}$, we usually refer to the induced topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ from the standard topology $\mathbb{R}$ (with the standard metric).

Comment: Thanks for helping. Do you think I can buy some books like that? or in internet even?

Comment: Actually I am a student just started studying topology this semester, so I cannot give you too much experience on that. And I am not so sure whether there exists some topology which is of interesting structure on $\mathbb{Q}$. But $\mathbb{Q}$ is usually used to describe the concept of "nowhere dense". Also, there are typical topologies like co-finite topology, discrete topology, etc. If you are interested in topology and really want to buy a book, Munkres and Davis are recommended.  But if you just want to study the topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ only, I have totally no idea.

Comment: @LaurenceAgustinIbona-Timbal Btw, Eric's answer provided more information than I did.